# Как выбрать первую запись ассоциативного массива?

Tags: алгоритм, php

```
$array=array();
$array[key]='val';
$array[keya]='val1';
$array[keyb]='val2';
```

Как выбрать первый элемент? `$array[0]` не работает ...

Comment: Самый простой способ, не затрагивая внутренний указатель массива. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-first.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если надо получить значение первого элемента массива, не зная его ключа, то можно использовать функцию [array_shift()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.array-shift.html), но не всегда удобна тем, что этот элемент, она как бы вырезает из массива:

```
$array=array();
$array[key]='val';
$array[keya]='val1';
$array[keyb]='val2';

$first= array_shift($array);
echo $first; // val
print_r($array); // что осталось в массиве
Array
(
    [keya] => val1
    [keyb] => val2
)
```

Второй способ - это использовать указатель [current](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.current.html)

```
$array=array();
$array[key]='val';
$array[keya]='val1';
$array[keyb]='val2';

//reset($array); // можно использовать для полной уверенности, что указатель будет на первом элементе массива (не принципиально)
echo current($array); // val
```

Comment: вот же, [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) и есть правильный ответ в одну строку – ф-я возвращает этот самый первый элемент массива, никак не изменяя сам массив! @frgs, молодец, так и написал несколько поздно.

Comment: @Sergiks это не верно. `reset()` меняет позицию указателя. Если у вас массив возвращается геттером класса, код вида `reset($object->myArray);` приведет к ошибке `Indirect modification of overloaded property` - т. е. будет воспринят, как модификация.

Answer (score 7):

раз тема популярная, то оставлю своё просто решение

```
$imgs = [
    'first' => '213121321',
    'last' => '9898989',
];
$first = reset($imgs);
$last = end($imgs);
```

Comment: единственное, о чем тут не сказано - end() перемотает курсор массива в самый конец массива, поэтому влияет на вывод функции current(), но, в принципе, кто ей пользуется, скорее всего уже про это знает.

Answer (score 1):

Самый быстрый способ без какой бы то ни было модификации исходного массива:

```php
foreach ($array as $element) break;
```

`$element` теперь содержит первый элемент массива `$array`

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-first.php

```
$array[array_key_first($array)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   $FirstIndex = $array[$key];
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fullArray = ['key1' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2'];
$fullArray[array_keys($fullArray)[0]];
```

Получи все ключи ассоциативного массива в индексированный массив, выбери оттуда первое значение - оно будет являться первым ключом. Обратись по этому ключу к изначальному массиву.

Answer (score -3):

```
echo $array[key];
```

какой вопрос такой и ответ)